# Mockito doReturn always return NULL

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class that I wish to test using Mockito. The problem I am facing is that when the Mock is called it always returns a `null` value.

I can see when I debug that Mockito see the mock but always returns `null`. My understanding is that in the CUT that when the `client.sendMessage` is called it will return the value for `Transaction` that I have created in the `@Test`.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

The class under test:

```java
public String SendMessage(String ID, String body) {

    String receipt = null;
    Map<String, Integer> Transaction = null;

    try {

        Transaction = client.sendMessage(ID, body);

    } catch(Exception e) {

           receipt = "FAIL";

           return receipt;
    }

    receipt = Transaction.get("receipt").toString();         

    return receipt;
}
```

My test method is:

```java
@Mock
private MessageSenderClient client;

@InjectMocks
MessageSender ms; 

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testPushNotificationProcessorTransactionID() {

    String Id = "1234";
    String body = "Test Message";

    Map<String, Integer> Transaction = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Transaction.put("Id", 123456);

    client = Mockito.mock(PushNotificationClient.class);

    Mockito.doReturn(Transaction).when(client).sendMessage(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString()); 

    String transactionID = ms.SendPushMessage(Id, body);

    assertEquals(transactionID, "1");   
}
```

Comment: You override your mock at: `client = Mockito.mock(PushNotificationClient.class);`, so you define `Mockito.doReturn(Transaction).when(client).sendMessage(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString());`on the wrong mock.

Comment: Thanks dur, I removed the override and it is working as I hope.